# Is there a better way to iterate over fields of a struct?

Tags: go, struct

I have these two structs that I'm populating from a JSON file:

```
type transaction struct {
    Datetime time.Time       `json:"datetime"`
    Desc     string          `json:"desc"`
    Cash     decimal.Decimal `json:"cash"`
}

type branch struct {
    BranchName    string        `json:"branch-name"`
    Currency      string        `json:"currency"`
    Deposits      []transaction `json:"deposits"`
    Withdrawals   []transaction `json:"withdrawals"`
    Fees          []transaction `json:"fees"`
}
```

I need to implement a method that returns the sum of all the `Cash` fields of `Deposits`, `Withdrawals` and `Fees`, but I'm not sure how to abstract them into "slices of things with a `Cash` field". My current implementation just repeats the same code three times:

```
func (b branch) getCash(datetime time.Time) decimal.Decimal {
    cash := decimal.NewFromFloat(0)
    for _, deposit := range b.Deposits {
        if deposit.Datetime.Before(datetime) {
            cash = cash.Add(deposit.Cash)
        }
    }
    for _, withdrawal := range b.Withdrawals {
        if withdrawal.Datetime.Before(datetime) {
            cash = cash.Add(withdrawal.Cash)
        }
    }
    for _, fee := range b.Fees {
        if fee.Datetime.Before(datetime) {
            cash = cash.Add(fee.Cash)
        }
    }
    return cash
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: They aren't 'slices of things with a cash field', they are all transactions, which makes the problem a simple one of appending the various silces into one before iterating (per @Tyger's answer).

Comment: You're right, but in the future I might add another struct with a Cash field and that solution would stop working.

Comment: Yes, if you add another field, you will have to add the new field to be iterated as well. The other possibility would be to use reflection, but a lot more can go wrong with that. I would not go down that road.

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate duplicate code by looping over a slices of slices:

```
for _, transactions := range [][]transaction{b.Deposits, b. Withdrawals, b.Fees} {
    for _, transaction := range transactions {
        if transaction.Datetime.Before(datetime) {
            cash = cash.Add(transaction.Cash)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append to one array and iterate over that:

```
func (b branch) getCash(datetime time.Time) decimal.Decimal {
    cash := decimal.NewFromFloat(0)
    arr := append(b.Deposits, b.Fees...)
    arr = append(arr, b.Withdrawals...)
    
    for _, a := range arr {
        if a.Datetime.Before(datetime) {
            cash = cash.Add(a.Cash)
        }
    }
    return cash
}
```

Comment: You're right, but in the future I might add another struct with a Cash field and that solution would stop working.

Comment: @noibe can you give an example of this?